# How to install and work with Media wiki Donation Interface plugin

Tags: php, plugins, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am using media wiki to build a web application.

Media wiki is a web framework from wikipedia which is used to build websites.

Link to media wiki : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki
I am building a site called vanisource.org

I would like to built a donation interface page for my website.

While searching through google, I found that media wiki provides a plug in, which can be used for donations. 
The link to the plugin is www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DonationInterface

They provide an example on how this plugin will look like at

donate.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:FundraiserLandingPage&country=IN&uselang=en-gb&utm_medium=spontaneous&utm_source=fr-redir&utm_campaign=spontaneous

I tried to work with this extension as per the docs provided by media wiki.

I had worked accordingly, and changed the localsetting.php as what is told in the documentation.

I would like to put this donation plug in a page like it is shown at

> donate.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:FundraiserLandingPage&country=IN&uselang=en-gb&utm_medium=spontaneous&utm_source=fr-redir&utm_campaign=spontaneous

but it appears to be confusing to me since changing localsettings.php will not put a form in my website. I am missing something. I would like to know how should I proceed so that I could get the same donation form as in

donate.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:FundraiserLandingPage&country=IN&uselang=en-gb&utm_medium=spontaneous&utm_source=fr-redir&utm_campaign=spontaneous

Answer (score 1):

So, have you actually downloaded the extension package and placed it on your server under the extensions folder? I see you've edited your localsettings.php but I'm not sure what else you've done to make USE of this extension.

You have to download the extension as is noted on the sidebar of 
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DonationInterface
at
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExtensionDistributor/DonationInterface

and then follow the instructions as well after the section of code for your localsettings.php

```
 require_once( "$IP/extensions/DonationInterface/DonationInterface.php" );
```

which include configuring which payment gateways you want to allow and other configurations.

You also have to create the page itself, it will not autopopulate a page just because you placed it in the localsettings.php

Comment: Can you please specify how and where to create the page that you are mentioning to auto-populate the donation content? Here is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75157449/how-to-install-and-start-accepting-donation-using-extension-donationinterface-in) I put on StackOverflow it has code that I'm using for my LocalSettings.php.